# How do you message/email the purchaser an order update?

Tags: 7, commerce

Previously in ubercart 3.x you were able to send messages and log admin notes on each order page. How can this be done using Drupal Commerce? I want to be able to message the purchaser in the order invoice page and also add internal notes if necessary. Which module(s) would I need to achieve this? Can you provide a screenshot of it in action?

Answer (score 3):

Since Drupal Commerce is based on the Rules module, you can simple create a custom rule which watches order status and react when one is changed.

Assuming you have Rules UI enabled you can go to: `admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/import`

Here is a simple Rule which you can import:

```
{"rules_admin_order_update" : {
    "LABEL" : "Admin order update",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_order_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "commerce-order:status" ],
          "value" : [ "commerce-order-unchanged:status" ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "admin@domain.dk",
          "subject" : "Update",
          "message" : "The order changed to [commerce-order:status-title]."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can then change the add more info, change parameters etc.

Hope this can get you going. :)

Comment: its not just update status i want to notify customers about. I want to be able to send a message to customers and also show internal log information on when things were changed from processing to shipped.

Comment: Then I'd take a look at how Commerce Kickstart 2.x rigs this all up using Message / Commerce Message. You would just need a UI for adding comments to the order (we do it via Message) and then Rules on the various triggers to send the e-mails out.